# Monitor ThreadPool use

Tags: wcf, threadpool

I wish to do some benchmarking on a busy WCF service (IIS-hosted, PerSession). Since WCF gets a new ThreadPool thread for each service call, I'd like to know if the ThreadPool's max threads count is ever reached, and if I should increase it (SetMaxThreads). The only way to get hard facts I can think of is to instrument the code with ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads. Is there any way for me to monitor if ThreadPool has reached max threads and is waiting for threads to be released? Thanks.