# How to track .Net thread pool usage?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

AFAIK some methods in the .Net library are able to do **I/O jobs asynchronously without consuming a thread from the pool**.

If my information are correct the **WebClient** *Async methods do that.

I'd like to verify it by checking that effectively threads from the pool are not used during a download.

So my general question is : **how can I monitor the current state of the thread-pool?**

- number of threads
- number of busy threads

Is there some **API** (*GetAvailableThreads*?) or **performance counters** that would give this information?

---

EDIT: here are some more details

I'm writing a simple benchmark for educational purposes:

```
string[] urls = Enumerable.Repeat("http://google.com", 32).ToArray();
/*{
    "http://google.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://microsoft.com",
    "http://wikipedia.com",
    "http://cnn.com",
    "http://facebook.com",
    "http://youtube.com",
    "http://twitter.com"
};*/

/*Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int wt, cpt;
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out wt, out cpt);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", wt, cpt);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });*/

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    webClient.DownloadString(url);
    Console.WriteLine("Got '{0}'", url);
}
stopwatch.Stop();

TimeSpan sequentialTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

stopwatch.Restart();
CountdownEvent cde = new CountdownEvent(1);
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    cde.AddCount();
    webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (_, __) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got '{0}'", __.UserState);
        cde.Signal();
    };
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url), url);
}
cde.Signal();
cde.Wait();
stopwatch.Stop();

TimeSpan asyncTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

stopwatch.Restart();
ThreadLocal<WebClient> threadWebClient = new ThreadLocal<WebClient>(() => new WebClient());
urls.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(urls.Length).ForAll(url => threadWebClient.Value.DownloadString(url));
stopwatch.Stop();

TimeSpan PLinqTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine("Sequential time: {0}.", sequentialTime);
Console.WriteLine("PLinq time: {0}.", PLinqTime);
Console.WriteLine("Async time: {0}.", asyncTime);
```

I'm comparing :

- naive sequential loop
- **PLINQ** loop
- **async I/Os**

The interesting part are the last two.

I expect and try to prove that async I/Os are:

- **faster** because they will create less pressure on the pool (less threads need to be created...)
- **lighter** because they will consume less thread of the pool

My "benchmark" shows that it's faster and I guess that's because the pool does not need to allocate new threads for each request whereas with PLINQ each parallel request will block one thread.

Now I'd like to check the numbers about thread consumption.

The commented task was a poor attempt to monitor the pool. It may be the good starting point but until now the result are not really consistent with what I expect: it never displays that more than 3/4 threads are consumed, whereas I expect something like 32 threads busy.

I'm open to any idea to enhance it or better any other use-case that would clearly highlight the differences between the two approaches.

Hope this is clearer now, and sorry for not having provided the details sooner. :)

Comment: @downvoters: if you have any reason to downvote please share. If you haven't just go your way. Thanks. :)

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering also why there were 2 downvotes. If downvoters don't give a reason in comments, it does not help OP rectify the question to satisfy downvoters' reason for downvoting. Otherwise, OP will never know if it was simply out of zeal.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Google of course (found this kind of stuff : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx but seems quite basic and what I've tried is not consistent with expected results), SO (found this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712322/monitor-threadpool-use but "empty"), I've checked PerfMon .Net counters => nothing. Conclusion : I'm seeking for real life feedback from someone that would I've used it or knows what to do and what to avoid. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek I think people (not me) downvoted because the topic is really broad. You might want to add some so that people know what you are expecting.

Comment: @Win: I'll update with some stuff. :)

Comment: I think this question is fine. I have upvoted. OP has enough rep for us to assume that some prior research was done without a resolution.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: thanks for this vote of confidence. :)

Comment: Your benchmark could use a little work, I would run the entire benchmark suite a few times (and throw out the first runs) or run each test individually from a cold start. How it is written right now the tests are unfair to the first method to run due to it having to do all the work of having non cached DNS lookups and having to have the IL code for `WebClient` JIT'ed the first time the methods are called.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: it's why I've swapped PLINQ and async I/O, to be as fair as possible. But indeed I should put the sequential loop last. And I run them many times commenting some parts. the result are quite consistent: sequential loop is "slow", PLINQ and I/O are quick but I/O is better, particularly when there is more URLs (I guess because the pool struggles to create threads for each parallel request...)

Comment: I think this is a great question. I am trying to set some small sample myself to learn from the threadpool. On thing to note as it applies here is that the maxconnection limits the number of connections. You can create a maximum of two connections to a specific IP address from each AppDomain in your process. For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/821268

Comment: You can increase it in machine.config. For example: <connectionManagement>  <add address="*" maxconnection="10">  </connectionManagement>. Maybe its better to use some other blocking IO as you might get throttled by the servers you are hitting.

Comment: That machine config has some more important connections regarding the threadpool. Check this artcile esp wth to minWorkerThreads https://www.infoworld.com/article/3201030/understand-the-net-clr-thread-pool.html

Answer (score 2):

The ThreadPool class provides the GetAvailableThreads method which "Retrieves the difference between the maximum number of thread pool threads returned by the GetMaxThreads method, and the number currently active." [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can capture the ratio thustly:

```
        int workerThreads;
        int completionPortThreads;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} threads available", workerThreads, completionPortThreads);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer *woogy*. This is what I've found and used as a first try. But as I've said in my question and comments I must be misusing it because the results are not what I expect. I think this is due to too short timings. I'll try to simulate a very long server with a local PHP script hosted in Apache that just sleeps say 10 seconds. This way my "benchmark" will be more predictable and be able to more easily capture what I hope is the behavior I expect. I'll come back with the results of this test.

Comment: @Pragmateek any thoughts what is the better way?

Comment: @codebased Sorry but if I remember well I had not implemented my idea. Maybe since then the .Net framework has fixed/enhanced/added some API to do the job...